# Whenever an exception occurred , should we log the stacktrace?

Tags: java, exception, logging

Almost every logging implementation has feature to log the exception stacktrace.

So, in case of any exception (including RuntimeException) , should we log the stacktrace ?
Or Should this be dependant on our business logic, as sometimes we raise the exception
to indicate a configuration problem or for some other purpose ?

Comment: only e.getMessage() also gives us some hint, dont need to print whole stacktrace. Also it depends on traffic on the application,developer's requirement.

Comment: yes that's right. However, the philosophy is that if some application is not running, then developers are used to see the stacktrace. There might be different reasons behind the failure. Offcourse, we can log the error message however logging stacktrace will show you that it's an application bug...... Need some experts view on this ..... :-$ !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Logging the stack trace is perfectly acceptable. It may even help developers debug issues faster. However, there are a few gotchas you must consider very strictly.

1. **IMPORTANT** Make sure there are no sensitive details in the stack trace. For example, internal details of proprietary libraries, user credentials, etc. should be cleaned out before logging.
2. From a usability standpoint, make sure that this logged error is not thrown up to your actual UI. Most customers would not appreciate seeing the big wall of technical function details. Restrict it to a log file or an "Advanced" section in the error report
3. Use logging levels to filter log output. Log these stack traces to a low priority level, such as `LogLevel.DEBUG` or `LogLevel.INFO`. In this way, you can easily turn on/off the detailed logging and make sure that log files are not filled up too fast.

Comment: "Logging the stack trace is perfectly acceptable"

What if clients looked at the log file and found a stacktrace. They assume that it's a bug even if it's just a configuration 
problem on UI. You are true that this will help developer to look at the logs with ease but once the development
is complete then it's all our clients who are going to see the logs. Isn't it ?

Comment: Note point 3. Most logging frameworks have the ability to externally  control the log level. This should be used to prevent log output in normal scenarios. But the code should still have that logging so that it can be turned on when required.

Comment: Yes this is right .... !!!! Agreed

Comment: I just realized the thing I used to do with Maven.
If maven failed to locate some dependency then it just abort the build and put a one line message that this 'xyz' dependency is not found.
But when i run it with -X option, i would see a stacktrace. 
So, i guess we should always log stacktrace if we have but with proper log level.